# Get a file from anonfiles with wget

Tags: bash

I am looking for a solution to directly get a file hosted on https://anonfiles.com/

Actually, I am trying to deposit a ZIP file (which is autorized) and get it via a simple `wget`(Linux) and via `bitsadmin.exe`(Windows)
The transfer proceeds correctly, but my downloaded file size is only of 4k with the good name.

If I try to download this file via my browser all works perfectly.

I specify that I am using the direct link which is like this
https://cdn.anonfiles.com/abcefghijkl.zip

Any idea ? May be it is not possible.

Comment: do you know about `wget` and `curl`? They have options that allow retrieving remote files. Find an intro page on the web, then search here for questions that include `wget` or `curl` to move forward. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonfiles.com protects bandwidth stealing using the HTTP referer header. You need to pass a referer in the anonfiles.com domain. For example:

```
wget --referer=https://anonfiles.com/ https://cdn.anonfiles.com/1394726793646.jpg
```